# How to dynamically add a dataentry form in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have to create a data entry form in asp.net webforms where the user could enter several member details. Each member detail will have about twenty data items such as FirstName, Lastname, DateOfBirth etc. The number of members entered can be anywhere from one to say twenty.

Once all the members entered or during the entry process, they should be able to go to the previous or next entry and make changes. Essentially there should be a Next and Previous buttons which will traverse the pages. At the end when the Save button is clicked all the entered data should be saved.

I have created a UserControl, which has all the textboxes to enter data. I have created five hardcoded panels which display the usercontrol five times. This makes the total members that could entered as five.

I would like to replace this hardcoded model with a dynamically added panel, when the next button is clicked.

Please let me know how this could be achieved. Or if there is a better architecture please let me know. I tried the wizard control, but it was too cumbersome in maintaining the previously entered values and traversing data using Next and Previous buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could add the controls dynamically to the page using:

```
Page.Controls.Add(new MyControl());
```

You'll have to find a temporary store for the data entered in the controls though such as Session.

```
Session["addedControls"] = myControls;
```

You can track the number of controls they add and then loop though and save all the data to whatever permanent store you're using.

There's an example of this here: http://howto.jamescarnley.com/2008/05/adding-fields-dynamically-in-aspnet.html

Storing the entire control in session does have it's drawbacks such as the overhead involved, you could just store the data which is more efficient but is a tiny bit more effort to implement.
This will also only work if they have cookies enabled.

Alternatively you could have a drop down list for them to select the number of entries they wish to make and display that number of controls by calling Page.Controls.Add the number of required times. Then just save them all in bulk at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically add the controls you need to input a new member easily enough in javascript. What you propose sounds like a nightmare to me. I'd put up a page with the controls to add a member and an 'Add Member' button. When the Add Member button is clicked - I would save the member to the database, retrieve a list of members added in this session - and display the names of the members in a list to the right of the 'Add Member' area of the page. If they want to review a member they can click on their name and you can show that member ready to be edited. Or they can add another member until they have finished. What you are trying to do is going to be a nightmare to manage and won't be any easier for the user to use.

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic controls will be very difficult and not user friendly as it may require refresh the page or using update panel

in your case, I would recommend doing it all from JavaScript using Knockout, This is a full sample [Knockout Grid](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html)

Make sure after adding or editing the grid, you will serialize the JavaScript objects into string using JSON.Stringify and add this text to a hidden field.

On form submission, just get the hidden field value, use newtonsoft json library to convert the string into an object and fee free to use the object which will be a list of your model (ex: Order).

Compared to dynamic controllers, this is more manageable and user friendly